# Where can one buy vegan winter earmuffs?

Tags: veganism, clothing, shopping

### Update

Found [this set of earmuffs](http://a.co/iDHnz4S) after including "polar fleece" in the search results.

Here is [another pair](http://amzn.eu/6hFnY0L) available in the UK found by a different user.

---

### Original Question

I've been finding it difficult to find winter earmuffs that do not have fleece, cashmere, or fur (it appears as though "faux-fur" doesn't necessarily mean no fur).

[This](http://a.co/htQAtSs) is an example of the style of earmuffs I'm looking for, that I have not been able to find.

Websites like [Vaute Couture](https://vautecouture.com/), [Unicorn Goods](https://unicorngoods.com/), and [Amazon](https://smile.amazon.com/) didn't have earmuffs show up. Google results do have a few, but they're usually just fluffballs around the ears.

Are there any examples of similar types of winter headgear that are vegan?

Comment: Do you mean fleece as in wool from a sheep or goat, or as in the synthetic polyester fabric (technically I believe it's "polar fleece", but the "polar" is often left out in descriptions of clothing)?

Comment: @Erica I was referring to fleece as in wool. I didn't realize that "polar" can be left out in item descriptions. I did some checking and did indeed find polar fleece options that are completely synthetic.

Comment: Instead of updating the question post with a solution, please post an answer (and [edit] out the solution from the question post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching on the Amazon (since you posted your example from there) I was able to easily find either [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01IZAOHP0) or [these](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Beechfield-Suprafleece-Anti-Pilling-Unisex-Winter/dp/B00FMEUQW6) earmuffs. Neither of those match your preferred style perfectly, with the first ones having a thin connecting part (and by the way, I have seen this style of earmuffs with vegan materials in loads of clothing shops in the UK, for example in Primark) and the second ones not having the knitted pattern, although I suppose it is not usual (if possible) to have knitted polyester.

This may not answer your question perfectly, but I thought I will ad my two cents. Good luck with finding the earmuffs :).

Comment: I'll mark this as the correct. I ended up finding [this set of earmuffs](http://a.co/iDHnz4S), which was similar to your second result. Once I started including "polar fleece" in the search results, I was able to find a few.

Comment: I am glad you found what you were looking for :)